# Query to filter multiple elements from the array in results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I do have this one working if I want to query attributes of employee by specifying a single email ID.

```
db.employee.find({},{
                _id: 0,
                employee: {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        email: "john@companyx.com"
                    }
                }})
```

Lets say if I want to query by specifying more than one email ID to get attributes of multiple employee. 
I read through, it has something to do with $or operator, but I am not sure how to lay that one out..

My mongoDB data as per below example:

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("53dbb05fa976627439d43884"),
 "employee" : [ 
  {
    "email" : "john@companyx.com",
    "deptName" : "x",

}, 
{
    "email" : "keen@companyx.com",
    "deptName" : "y",

},
{
    "email" : "hung@companyx.com",
    "deptName" : "y",

}
 ]
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array filtering can only be done by the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/). It allows more manipulation of the document than is available by basic projection.

Just like any query though, you should always use a [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline first in order to make use of in index where possible. regardless of what other operations are being performed afterwards:

```js
db.employee.aggregate([

    //  Always match first to reduce results
    { "$match": {
         "employee.email": { "$in": ["john@companyx.com", "keen@companyx.com"] }
    }},

    // Unwind to de-normalize the array elements as documents
    { "$unwind": "$employee" },

    // Match to "filter" the array content
    { "$match": {
         "employee.email": { "$in": ["john@companyx.com", "keen@companyx.com"] }
    }},

    // Group back to a document with the array
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "employee": { "$push": "$employee" }
    }},

    // Optionally project to remove the "_id" field from results
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "employee": 1
    }}
])
```

So that explains the basic process. After finding the "documents" that match your conditions, you use [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to effectively make each element of the array an document on it's own, sharing any parent fields. The additional [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) is there to "filter" those elements in the results. When the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) is done, then only the matched elements are put back into the array.

With MongoDB 2.6 you can do this in a different way that should work better with larger arrays. There are new operators such as [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) for processing an array "in-line" without using [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). There is also other "set" filtering options as [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/). So you can do this where your documents always contain unique "email" values in their own array:

```js
db.employee.aggregate([

    //  Always match first to reduce results
    { "$match": {
         "employee.email": { "$in": ["john@companyx.com", "keen@companyx.com"] }
    }},

    // Project filtered array content "in-line"
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "employee": {
            "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$employee",
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": {
                        "$cond": [
                            { "$or": [
                                { "$eq": [ "$$el.email", "john@companyx.com" ] },
                                { "$eq": [ "$$el.email", "keen@companyx.com" ] }
                            ]},
                            "$$el",
                            false
                        ]
                    }
                }},
                [false]
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

Aside from the new operators mentioned earlier, the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator is used here to evaluate each element of the array that is passed through [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to see if it meets the conditions. If so the element is is returned in the resulting array, otherwise the element is `false`.

The [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) operator then "filters" any `false` values from the "set" returned, as would be any duplicates so the array elements would need to be unique in each document as mentioned.

For "non-unique" elements, there is always this alternate to the first method in modern versions as well:

```js
db.employee.aggregate([

    //  Always match first to reduce results
    { "$match": {
         "employee.email": { "$in": ["john@companyx.com", "keen@companyx.com"] }
    }},

    // Redact removes document levels that do not match the condition
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": [
            { "$or": [
                { "$eq": [ 
                    { "$ifNull": [ "$email", "john@companyx.com" ] },
                    "john@companyx.com"
                ]},
                { "$eq": [ 
                    { "$ifNull": [ "$email", "keen@companyx.com" ] },
                    "keen@companyx.com"
                ]}
            ]},
            "$$DESCEND",
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    }}
])
```

This uses [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) in a slightly contrived way to remove the array elements from the documents that do not match the condition. The catch here is that `$redact` is recursive, so that is why we test for the presence of the tested field and where it does not exist just return a value to match. Really only needs one [**`$ifNull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) statement in there actually.

Essentially, whatever approach you choose, it is the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) that has the "souped up" manipulation of documents that does more than basic projection can.

Comment: Thanks @Neil, such a brilliant explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood what you meant, I think that the solution for you is the `$in` operator, and I think that you should put your condition in the selector parameter, not in the projection one, if I have understood your needs. So your query would be something like:

```
db.employee.find({email:{$in:["email1@foo.bar", "email2@bar.foo"]}},{_id:0})
```

Comment: I have added the mongodb data inside the question also...I guess that add into the complexity as well

Comment: Yes, I didn't understood how your data was formatted. So you can't do that with projection, because $elemMatch returns only one element from your array. You need a more complex aggregation

Answer (score 0):

Projection operator **$elemMatch** only returns one element from the array, so I think you may consider **aggregate**, like

```
var emails = [ "john@companyx.com", "hung@companyx.com" ];
var match = {
    $match : {
        "employee.email" : {
            $in : emails
        }
    }
};

db.employee.aggregate([ match, {
    $unwind : "$employee"
}, match, {
    $group : {
        _id : "$_id",
        employee : {
            $push : "$employee"
        }
    }
}, {
    $project : {
        _id : 0,
        employee : 1
    }
} ]);
```

Comment: got this uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: bad query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $in",
 "code" : 16810,
 "ok" : 0
}

Comment: @Fairul, Sorry, there is a mistake in **$match** part. Fixed.